# Anyway to subtype "string" based on pattern in .NET or Java?

Tags: c#, java, .net

Let's say I wanna create a ReadFile method which will accepts either

http://.../url

or

c:...\localfile

What I want is Expressiveness for User of my method (even if it happens to be myself in the first place) which should be the purpose of a modern programming language.

At the same time I don't want the procedural if in implementation but something more OOP with type checking at compile time like for a true type.

So would be nice if I could somehow define a "string" subtype http or c:...

Instead of

```
ReadFile(String aString)
```

and test String to be of type http or local

I could use polymorphism and define

```
ReadFile(SubtypeString1 aString) 

ReadFile(SubtypeString2 aString)
```

where ReadFile would continue to **accept normal string** but would trigger in background by the .net runtime the checking of 2 class associated with the definition above.

Is there a way to do this somehow in C# or Java ?

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can't subclass String in either C# or Java. It's final (Java) and sealed (.NET) to prevent subclassing.

You could create your own class to *wrap* a string, of course, and then create your overloads. However, overload resolution is generally performed at compile time rather than execution time, so it wouldn't do what you wanted it to ("triggering in background"). The closest equivalent would be to use dynamic typing in C# 4 to perform overload resolution at execution time... but I still don't think that's a good idea.

It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do. You might want to create some sort of `Resource` base type, a factory method to create a `Resource` from a String, and then two subclasses - e.g. `FileResource` and `WebResource` to represent local files and web resources respectively. You would then put appropriate abstract methods in the base class and implement them in each subclass.

EDIT: Your question asked for an answer which is *expressive* - and that's what this is. You're separating the "work out what this string means" from "read data from the resource", allowing you to pass resources around your API, *expressing* the meaning clearly. Passing a bare string, it could be *anything* - including something which is neither a filename nor a URL.

Comment: so much overdesigned a simple wish! O_O

Comment: He wants to pass just a string. Some much for Resources or Factories. But based on the value he wants different methods to be invoked. All he needs is an if() inside the single method, no need to architect any even slightly complicated class hierarchies.

Comment: @road: If he just wanted to pass a string, he could do so... but he appears to want to create subclasses himself. The *question* introduced a class hierarchy before there were any answers. If the `if` is really only in a single method, that's fine - but in many other situations, it's useful to have an abstraction for "a resource which can be fetched later".

Comment: How would you automatically call the checking method ?

Comment: @user310291: Which checking method? You'd call the factory method once to create a `Resource` from the `String`, and then use methods on the `Resource` class to access the data.

Comment: By subtype I mean also type checking at compile time like for a true type.

Comment: @user310291: I haven't got time to write a code sample right now, but I think my post is reasonably clear. And yes, once you've got this type hierarchy, you get compile-time type checking which you wouldn't have with your overload-performed-at-execution-time request in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that you want a factory that would analyse your input string and then create the file reading object based upon what your string looks like:

```
class FileReader { }
class UrlFileReader : FileReader { }
class LocalFileReader : FileReader { }

class FileReaderFactory
{
   public FileReader Create(string uri)
   {
      if(IsUrl(uri))
      {
         return new UrlFileReader();
      }

      if(IsLocalFile(uri))
      {
         return new LocalFileReader();
      }

      return FileReader();
   }
}
```

Or following Jon's idea, you could return a `Resource` that could be passed to your reader class.

Comment: What I want is an expressive syntax: pass string and not classes. So I'm not sure that passing a factory would fit :)

Comment: @user310291: Using a String is *less* expressive than abstracting the idea that this is something representing a resource, and passing that around instead.

Comment: ... but at the same time there is no reason to invent a type for a single method in a single class.

Comment: Expressive for the User of the method.

Comment: @user310291: Again, it's more expressive: if the user of the method sees that it accepts a `Resource` parameter, that expresses more information than if it just accepts a `string` parameter, isn't it? The string might be anything - the resource definitely represents a resource.

Answer (score 1):

No, except:

DIY polymorhism:

```
 public void readFile(String s) {
     if( s.matches(HTTP_REGEXP) ) readFileFromHTTP(s);
     else if( s.matches(FILE_REGEXP) ) readFileFromLocal(s);
     else ...
 }

 private void readFileFromHTTP(String s) {...}
 private void readFileFromLocal(String s) {...}
```

Comment: OK seems close have to think about it because I don't like the if.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String wrapper classes that are supposed to be used for this particular purpose and that will likely make your implementation easier and less error prone as well.

In Java this would be classes java.io.File and java.io.URL:

```
public void readFile( URL url )
{
...
}

public void readFile( File file )
{
...
}
```